# Dynamically create anchor tag

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a textbox named "txt_contact". User fills his contact including his email id, for example:

```
Contact:   Reggie Frederick, Email: regtnt@rediffmail.com; Mob: +91 984 807 7749
```

I am saving this information in the database. But I want "regtnt@rediffmail.com" as an anchor tag and when clicked, it should redirect to rediffmail.com. What can be done to achieve this??

This is what I have already tried.

```
    string cont = txt_contact.Text;
    Regex regx1 = new Regex("http://([\\w+?\\.\\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\\~\\!\\@\\#\\$\\%\\^\\&amp;\\*\\(\\)_\\-\\=\\+\\\\\\/\\?\\.\\:\\;\\'\\,]*)?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    MatchCollection matches = regx1.Matches(cont);
    foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            cont = cont.Replace(match.Value, "<a class='abc' href='" + match.Value + "'>" + match.Value + "</a>");
        }
```

NOTE: User can fill any email account in the textbox (gmail, yahoo etc)

Comment: Don't store it with an anchor. Make an Email field and store it in that field in the database. Then you can do anything with it on reading afterwards without having to do all sorts of jumping through loops. Always keep your data clean from formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped me:

When I show data, I am writing a regular expression for Email.

```
 $(document).ready(function () { 
        var regEx = /(\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)/;
        var contact = $("span[id*=lblContact]")
        $(contact).filter(function () {
            return $(this).html().match(regEx);
        }).each(function () {
            $(this).html($(this).html().replace(regEx, "<a style=color:blue href=\"mailto:$1\">$1</a>"));
        });
    })
```